# Multithreaded FTP uploader for a single file

Tags: java, ftp

I'm trying to implement a Maven plugin to upload an assembly (a very huge one, > 1.5 Gb) to the FTP in a multithreaded manner to save time during build preparation. Is there any specific library I can use for that? Or if there's a way to assemble uploaded parts right on the FTP server?

Many Thanks,
Vlad.

Comment: You can use commons-net api to upload files to FTP

Comment: Why do you a think multiple connections to an ftp server to send one file will be faster? If there is a rate limit per connection then you are better off fixing the server.

Comment: @Srikanth Venkatesh I've tried different libraries to do that. The first one I tries was exactly commons-net.

Comment: @IanNorton well I've proven that multiple connections to FTP server to send one file are 10 times faster. I.e. if I split destination file into 20 smaller parts it takes up to 10 times less time to upload rather than uploading one big file. Why did I ask this question as I used Total Commander FTP uploader, FileZilla, Java single Thread, Java multithread. For TC FTP and Java sigle thread upload I'm getting about 100 Kb/s upload speed. For the Filezilla I'm getting a speed of about 1Mb/s. Java multithread - 100 kb/s per thread which gives 1Mb/s as Filezilla does. So the question is still open.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP client upload limitation is driving by TCP Window Size 64KB and latency of connection. I proven the concurrent upload speed are not limited by bandwidth only. Means even you have a 100Mbps connection link with 50ms latency, the max. upload speed for single FTP thread just have 1280Kbyte/s.

Solution1, Change the TCP Window Size to 129KByte the transmit data will be double. 
Solution2, Allow more than 1 thread with same source IP and source file.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly will multithreading save time? You will almost certainly be bandwidth-limited, and you can't multithread that.

Comment: please see my comment addressed to IanNorton as I suppose it answers your question.

Comment: @Vlad it doesn't. You haven't explained how it can save time. Your observations are contrary to logic and therefore suspect.